# Can't point Perforce workspace to a different stream

Tags: perforce, p4v

My main Perforce workspace has somehow ended up pointing to a task stream, rather than our main stream. Now it won't let me change back. When I right click and edit the workspace to try and point it at the main stream I get this error:

> Client 'my_workspace' has files opened from a task stream; must revert, or revert -k before switching.

I went through every file and only found one which was mapped to the task stream workspace- I have resolved this. So now all my files are mapped to my Main workspace, and are meant for our main stream.

Comment: It's saying you have a file **opened** in a task stream. So look at your **opened** files. You have to either submit those open task stream files, or revert those opened task stream files, before you switch; otherwise you can't switch.